# Why aren't the walls also made of Schach?

Tags: sukkah, yetziat-mitzrayim, schach, masechet-sukkah

1. The Gemmorah learns the obligation of Succah from the Clouds of Glory that surrounded the Jewish people on Exodus (and later).
2. It also learns (at least one opinion) that the Schach must resemble a Cloud that "stems from the soil and is not impure" ([Succah 11b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.2.6?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Sukkah.11b.14&lang2=bi)).
3. IIRC there were a total of 7 clouds - one in every direction and one in front of the camp.

Bearing that resemblance, I'd expect the whole Succah to be made of Schach including the floor, likening the Clouds of Glory. Considering the minimal size of 80x80x80cm that would not be so difficult. As we all know that's not a requirement.

Why not?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.630.1?lang=he ובהגהות אשרי (פרק ראשון סימן כד) נמצא בלשון זה: ולפי הירושלמי צריך ליזהר שלא לעשות דפנות מדבר המקבל טומאה, או שאין גידולו מן הארץ

Comment: Also Sukkah 7b דכתיב וסכות על הארון את הפרוכת פרוכת מחיצה וקא קרייה רחמנא סככה אלמא מחיצה כסכך בעינן Apparently we don't all know what you know.

Comment: @DoubleAA Correct. That's the opinion of R. Yoshiya (regarding חמתה מחמת דפנות). Aruch Hashulchan suggests that the Yerushalmi (according to this *girsa*) is following him.

Comment: @JoelK Thank you, it's good to know that the great minds think alike. Sorry, who's אשרי? And does he connect it to the Clouds?

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%92%D7%94%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%99

Comment: @AlBerko He doesn’t mention the clouds, just refers to the Yerushalmi (which as far as I can tell also doesn’t mention them).

Comment: Rashi asks & answers on 12a: רש"י על סוכה י״ב  - 
כשרין לדפנות - דכל סוכה הכתוב סכך משמע דדופן לא איקרי סוכה ודנפקא לן (לעיל סוכה ו:) דפנות מבסכת בסכת בסכות מייתורא דקראי ילפינן ולא ממשמעותא הלכך סוכות תעשה באספך מגרנך אסככה הוא דקאי: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.12a.8?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en